# ES6 lost scope when method is assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I found and unexpected behavior. Can anyone explain why "this" is lost when a method is referenced to a variable like in an example below?

```js
class Foo {
  static bar() {
   return 'bar'; 
  }
  
  baz() {
   return this.constructor.bar(); 
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

foo.baz(); // works fine

const baz = foo.baz;

baz(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/sznowicki/c076c52a0242c77a3044f4a79e9af4c3

Comment: In short, `this` depends entirely on how the function is invoked, not where it was declared.

Comment: In JavaScript, functions/methods are not autobound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
const baz = foo.baz;
```

You can do:

```
const baz = foo.baz.bind(foo);
```

This will make sure that `foo` is bound to `this` in the method call when you run:

```
baz();
```

See the docs for more info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: .apply also runs the method. The use case here is that I want to expose some methods to a global object which works as an API for some scripts.

And I'm curious why exactly it happens.

Comment: just for a comment
`` const baz = foo.baz.bind(foo);
``
does the job

Comment: @sznowicki You can use `.bind` instead of `.apply` to set `this` without invoking the function. However, this basically just wraps your original function in a new function that stores a private reference to `this` and then runs `.apply` on the original function when invoked.

Comment: That is the solution for a problem. For some reason, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `this` as an extra argument being passed to methods that carries an object on which method was invoked.
So: `foo.baz()` is invoked on `foo` and `foo` is passed as `this`.
But `baz()` is just a **function** (not method as it doesn't remember object on which it was defined previously). Here it is hard to tell what value `this` will hold (also depends on [`'use strict';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)).

## How to Handle It

1. Bind it: `const foo = bar.bind(instance)`.
2. Call it with `bar.apply(instance, ...)` or `bar.call(instance, ...)`.
3. Wrap instance in function: `const foo = function() { instance.bar() }` or `const foo = () => instance.bar()`.
4. Remember, that arrow functions handle `this` [differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) from plain functions.